# NullPointerException con Ucanaccess

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nullpointerexception

Tengo un problema, el cual es que el siguiente código me tira un `NullPointerException` en:

```
pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
```

Adjunto el código completo:

```
package com.gmail.brunodiazmartin5.banco.mysql;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

    public Connection connection;
    public ResultSet rs;
    public String bd, user, pass;
    public PreparedStatement pstm;

    public Conexion(String bd, String user, String pass){
        this.bd = bd;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;   
    }

    public void conectar(){
        try{
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+bd, user, pass);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public  boolean consultar(String user, String pass){
        boolean accepted = false;
        conectar();
        try {
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuarios");

            rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("Usuario").equals(user) && rs.getString("Pass").equals(pass)){
                    accepted = true;
                }else{
                    accepted = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        desconectar();

        return accepted;
    }

    public String getPrivilegio(String user){
        String privilegio = "";

        try {
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Tipo FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, user);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                String priv = rs.getString("Tipo");

                switch(priv){
                case "admin":
                    privilegio = "admin";
                    break;
                case "user":
                    privilegio = "user";
                    break;
                case "cliente":
                    privilegio = "cliente";
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

        return privilegio;
    }

    public ResultSet consultar(String dni){
        conectar();
        try {
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

        desconectar();

        return rs;
    }

    public void insertar(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, int saldo, String telefono, String telefono2){
        conectar();
        try {
            pstm  = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            pstm.setString(1, nombre);
            pstm.setString(2, apellidos);
            pstm.setString(3, dni);
            pstm.setInt(4, saldo);
            pstm.setString(5, telefono);
            pstm.setString(6, telefono2);
            pstm.executeQuery();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

        desconectar();
    }

    public void insertarSaldo(String dni, float saldo){
        conectar();

        desconectar();
    }

    public void retirarSaldo(String dni, String dni2, float saldo){
        String dniOrigen = dni;
        String dniDestino = dni2;
        float saldoR = saldo, saldoA = 0F;

        conectar();

        try {
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE DNI = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, dniOrigen);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                saldoA = rs.getInt("Saldo");
            }

            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET Saldo = ? WHERE DNI = ?");
            pstm.setFloat(1, saldoA - saldoR);
            pstm.setString(2, dniOrigen);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

        if(!dni2.equals(null)){
            try{
                pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE DNI = ?");
                pstm.setString(1, dniDestino);
                rs = pstm.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    saldoA = rs.getInt("Saldo");
                }

                pstm = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET Saldo = ? WHERE DNI = ?");
                pstm.setFloat(1, saldoA + saldoR);
                pstm.setString(2, dniDestino);
                rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        desconectar();
    }

    public void eliminar(String dni){
        conectar();
        try{
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE DNI = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, dni);
            pstm.executeQuery();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

        desconectar();
    }

    public void desconectar(){
        try {
            rs.close();
            pstm.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Prueba a inicializar connection.

Comment: Básicamente, `connection` es `null`. ¿No te sale antes un error informado de un problema en `conectar()`? NOTA: Es por eso que uno no se "come" las excepciones; si hay una excepción en `conectar()` entonces `connection` se queda a `null` y da más problemas más adelante.... o tratas la excepción o la lanzas de nuevo.

Comment: Vale, eso lo entiendo, lo que no entiendo es porque en null

Comment: ¿Pero te lanza una excepción en `conectar()` o no?

Comment: Si, pero no se porque se queda connection en null, la ruta de la base de datos esta bien.

Comment: Tu problema está en el método `conectar`, tu variable se queda nula. En lugar de ocultar la excepción con `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());` (**MUY** mala práctica) mejor usa `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)` que te brindará los detalles del problema, lo que puedes analizar y resolver. Fuera de eso, tienes un problema de diseño muy grave: `Connection` y demás no deberían ser atributos de la clase, deben ser variables de cada método.

Comment: Además, tienes un problema gravísimo de rendimiento. Tus queries deberían recibir los parámetros necesarios para devolver la data, para eso sirve la base de datos, no solo para almacenar información. Por ejemplo, el método `consultar(dni)` lee todos los usuarios de la bd y luego los filtra por el campo, esto bien se puede hacer en el query `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni = ?`.

Comment: hay una vieja teoria que dice que si no sabes que hacer con una excepcion.. lo mejor es que el programa pinche...